# Are Questions About Vocabulary/Definition On Topic?

Tags: discussion

I don't mean meta questions like defining science fiction vs fantasy, I mean questions about definitions of unfamiliar terms in works of science fiction.  Ordinarily I would think first of the English Language and Usage stack, but sometimes:

- It's not clear if the word is a real word;
- It's not clear if the word has an invented meaning in-work totally unrelated to normal usage;
- Someone familiar with the work may be able to provide special insights

The obvious-- perhaps even canonical-- author one might need these questions for is Gene Wolfe, although the term I want to ask about is found in David Zindell's books.

If it is on topic, is there a tag?  I searched for things like 'vocabulary', 'definition', etc, and came up completely cold.  If it is on topic and no tag yet exists, I would suggest either of those.

Comment: These questions are fine but we don’t need a vocabulary tag though.